# Oracle 11g order by behavior

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

With an Oracle 11g Database, in a select query with an `order by` on one column.

What is the ordering behavior for records having the same value?

I have found no clear information and it seems Oracle did not define any default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There is no defined behavior for rows with equal values in the column(s) you're ordering by. The database is free to return them in any internal order, much like there is no defined behavior for the order of rows returned by a query without an `order by` clause. Note that this means that subsequent executions of the same query may return the results in a different order.